# Nano edits to files revert after reboot every time

Tags: linux, kernel, nano

I am trying to get a settings on my kernel to save and after editing them they always flop back to the original settings after I restart, I write them out and save before exit.

```
sudo cpupower frequency-set -g balanced
```

and

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/*
```

to change frequency and lower the laptop temperature on my Ubuntu or Fedora machine, still running some passes to see which OS is more suitable for my needs; I have ran Nano to do the trick each boot and considering Gedit, also wondering if Vim or tee would do the trick? Or why they won't just save.

Comment: you will have to be specific about what files you are talking about. this almost certainly has nothing to do with the editor you are using.

Comment: i added some information.. sorry about that.

Comment: So I can't help but notice that neither of the things you listed are files that could be edited (with nano or another editor; one is a command, and the other is a reference to all files in a directory). What I have seen when I search `cpupower frequency-set` or `/sys/devices/` indicates that in modern linux, you would script setup for the devices with a custom systemd init script or scripts in a .profile or .rc file like .bashrc, so that it gets automatically executed.